# How to know if all the fields in a schema are filled or not?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongoose, joi

I have a schema as follows:

How do i check if all the fields in the schema are filled or not?

front-end(react.js) has an on boarding process, where in they need users who are logged in for the first time to go on the on-boarding process and the users who are logging- in for second or more times to be sent to other page. So, they require a boolean value from me. How do i get to know whether all data are been filled?

```
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  phoneNumber: { type: String },
  role: { type: String, default: 'user' },
  userDetails: {
    firstName: { type: String },
    lastName: { type: String },
    userName: { type: String },
    password: { type: String },
    email: { type: String },
    street_1: { type: String },
    street_2: { type: String },
    landmark: { type: String },
    city: { type: String },
    state: { type: String },
    zipcode: { type: String },
  },
  kycDetails: {
    aadharNumber: { type: String },
    aadharFront: {
      type: String,
    },
    aadharBack: {
      type: String,
    },
    panNumber: { type: String },
    panImage: {
      type: String,
    },
  },
  bankDetails: {
    accountNumber: { type: String },
    accountName: { type: String },
    bankName: { type: String },
    ifscCode: { type: String },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use validation package https://ajv.js.org/
to check all the fields You want with Json

for example

```
const nSchema = {
    type: 'object',
    properties: {
        phoneNumber: {type: 'string'},
        role: {type: 'string', enum:['user']},
    },
    required: ['phoneNumber', 'role'],
    additionalProperties: false
};
const valid = ajv.validate(nSchema, data);
if (!valid) {

}
```